# How to make a CSS HTML tab show by default

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a some HTML and CSS tabs for my website, and when it loads on to the page, the tabs are all minimized and you need to click on one to open it. How to I make the first one open by default

This is my code..

http://pastebin.com/vwtynTSV

To make this more clear, its for an ebay insert, so i cant do just make it load index.html#One off the bat.

Hey guys, i ended up using

thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if they're just using anchor tags to open up the new tabs. So if you're wanting your user to have the index page with the first tab open, have the index point to mywebsite.com/#One . That's even what they do on their demo page is just link you straight to the anchor of #one. [here](http://demo.webstutorial.com/css3-tabs/#One)